# MySQL LIMIT optimization issue

Tags: mysql, database, optimization, limit

I have the following MySQL query that I'm looking to make the LIMIT faster as it's running  VERY slow.  SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS equals about 114000 rows.

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS PStD.ProductID FROM ProductStoreDef PStD
    JOIN ProductSummary PS ON PStD.ProductID = PS.ProductID 
    JOIN MasterVendor MV ON MV.VendorID = PStD.MasterVendorID 
WHERE 
    PStD.SKUStatus = 'A' AND 
    MV.isActive = 1 AND 
    PStD.MasterCategoryID = 66 AND 
    PStD.CustomerPrice > 0
ORDER BY PStD.VendorName, PS.VendorPartNumber 
LIMIT 100000,50
```

The following is the EXPLAIN results

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+---------+-------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys                                                                                   | key             | key_len | ref                     | rows | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+---------+-------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | MV    | ALL    | PRIMARY,isActive,VendorID                                                                       | NULL            | NULL    | NULL                    | 2126 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort | 
|  1 | SIMPLE      | PStD  | ref    | PRIMARY,MasterVendorID,MasterCategoryID,SKUStatus,CustomerPrice,MasterVendCatID,ProdStoreStatus | MasterVendCatID | 8       | ecomm.MV.VendorID,const |   94 | Using where                                  | 
|  1 | SIMPLE      | PS    | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                                         | PRIMARY         | 4       | ecomm.PStD.ProductID    |    1 |                                              | 
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+---------+-------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Update: Solved this issue by creating a separate table that pre-calculates the sort order making the site run about 500x to 1000x faster.

Comment: Do you have indexes on the ProductStoreDef.VendorName and ProductSummary.VendorPartNumber columns?

Comment: remove SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS if possible, it will drastically slow down the query. And please show EXPLAIN for query

Comment: Absolutely no difference with or without SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS.  EXPLAIN looks the same.

Comment: @wonk0 In this case it should not slow down the query, because the query should process all the rows despite the SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the problem is sorting. In this case you may try to create these indexes, but I cannot guarantee anything:

```
ALTER TABLE `ProductStoreDef` ADD INDEX `ProductStoreDef_CIndex` (
    `ProductID` ASC, `MasterVendorID` ASC, `MasterCategoryID` ASC, 
    `SKUStatus` ASC, `CustomerPrice` ASC, `VendorName` ASC
);    
ALTER TABLE `ProductSummary` ADD INDEX `ProductSummary_CIndex` (
    `ProductID` ASC, `VendorPartNumber` ASC
);    
ALTER TABLE `MasterVendor` ADD INDEX `MasterVendor_CIndex` (
    `VendorID` ASC, `isActive` ASC
);
```

Comment: If this will not help then give me an EXPLAIN of your query again after you create these indexes.

Comment: ProductStoreDef Indexes:
PRIMARY KEY  (ProductID,StoreID),
KEY MasterVendorID (MasterVendorID),
KEY MasterCategoryID (MasterCategoryID),
KEY LastUpdate (LastUpdate),
KEY SKUStatus (SKUStatus),
KEY CustomerPrice (CustomerPrice),
KEY VendorName (VendorName),
KEY MasterVendCatID (MasterVendorID,MasterCategoryID),
KEY ProdStoreStatus (ProductID,StoreID,SKUStatus),
KEY StoreCat (StoreID,MasterCategoryID,CustomerPrice,SKUStatus),
KEY StoreLastUpdate (StoreID,LastUpdate),
KEY StoreID_2 (StoreID,MasterVendorID,MasterCategoryID,CustomerPrice,SKUStatus)

Comment: ProductSummary Indexes:
PRIMARY KEY  (ProductID),
KEY VendorPartNumber (VendorPartNumber),
KEY Quantity (Quantity)

MasterVendor Indexes:
PRIMARY KEY  (VendorID),
KEY isActive (isActive),
KEY LastUpdate (LastUpdate),
KEY Vendor (Vendor),
KEY VendorActive (VendorID,isActive)

Comment: @Jesse It's OK, You have one of my mentioned indexes. Now let's create the first two :)

Comment: @Jesse The problem is that none of your mentioned indexes helps for sorting. Yes, you have separate indexes for VendorName and VendorPartNumber but they cannot be used after the process of filtering. So you need to include them in the composite indexes (like in my answer). Note: the order matters.

Comment: Added your indexes and did an EXPLAIN.  Everything looks exactly the same and no speed up. :(

Comment: @Jesse Explain should be a little different. Are you sure that explain is exactly the same?

Comment: @Karolis let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1935/discussion-between-jesse-and-karolis)